# How to check if all of given values exists in table?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a list like '2,3,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,16,18,22,28,30'.
I have a table with columns gridConfigId and ownerId.
I need to find all gridConfigId which list of ownerId does not have at least one of the given set.

I try the query:

```
SELECT 
   gridConfigId, GROUP_CONCAT(ownerId separator ',') as userList
from 
   gridconfig_favourites gf
where 
   exists (select 1 from gridconfigs g where g.id=gf.gridConfigId and type='asset' and name='Photo Attributes')
GROUP BY gridConfigId
HAVING
   userList != '2,3,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,16,18,22,28,30';
```

But this variant does not work because ordering of `ownerId` can be different.
I was trying to add `ORDER BY gridConfigId, ownerId` but query does not work that way.

Comment: Can you share your sample input table and corresponding expected output?

Comment: You could use `HAVING count(distinct ownerId) != 14`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I've just add `ORDER BY ownerId` inside the GROUP_CONCAT.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(ownerId ORDER BY ownerId separator ',')
```

The result is the string with ordered ids inside. And i can compare ids list just like strings.

It is described in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat).